# Problem On Arithmetic Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Two series $S_1$ and $S_2$, each having $280$ terms, are $S_1 : 1, 8, 15, 22, \dots$ and $S_2 : 20, 23, 26, \dots$ respectively. How many terms of $S_1$ and $S_2$ are identical?

Comment: What have you tried? I would tell you to apply Chinese Remainder Theorem, if I were aware that you know it.

Answer (score 3):

$$S1:\{1+7d;0\le d\le279\}$$

$$S2:\{20+3D;0\le D\le279\}$$

We need $1+7d=20+3D\iff\dfrac{3(D+4)}7=d-1$ which is an integer

$\implies7|3(D+4)\implies7|(D+4)$ as $(3,7)=1$

$\implies D+4=7m\iff D=7m-4$ where $m$ is any integer

$0\le D\le279\implies0\le7m-4\le279\implies1\le m\le\dfrac{283}7<41$

and consequently, $d=3m+1$ and $0\le d\le279\implies0\le3m+1\le279\iff0\le m\le\dfrac{278}3<93$

$\implies1+7d=20+3D=20+3(7m-4)=21m+8$

So, there $40$ elements in common corresponding to  $1\le m<41$

Comment: If $D + 4 = 7m$, then $d = 3m + 1$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, Please find the updated version.